# Two functions; checking the input file and the text area and I also want to disable the submit button how do I make the functions into one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, textarea

1. this is my code and I have checked the values and disabled the submit button     when needed but the two functions conflict the with each other and I want one function to do both.

   ```
   //these are my inputs
   <input type = "file" name= "fotoimazhi" class = "inputfile"  id = "file" >
   <input  type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "Ngarko" id = "perzgjidh"         disabled>
   <textarea  id = "texti" type = "text" name= "fotoemer"  cols="40" 
      rows="5" ></textarea >

    //this is for the input type file
      $(document).ready(
         function(){
          $('input:file').change(
               function(){
                    if ($(this).val()) {
                     $('input:submit').attr('disabled',false);
                   // or, as has been pointed out elsewhere:
                   // $('input:submit').removeAttr('disabled'); 
               } 
           }
           );
        });

   //this is for text area

      $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.sendButton').attr('disabled',true);
         $('#texti').keyup(function(){
            if($(this).val().length !=0)
               $('.sendButton').attr('disabled', false);            
          else
           $('.sendButton').attr('disabled',true);
        })
      });
      </script>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
$('.sendButton').attr('disabled', false);
```

Try:

```
$('.sendButton').prop('disabled', false);
```

I recently read that with JQuery, one should use prop instead of attr for  "disabled" (and other properties, such as "checked").

You say that you have a "conflict" -- could you be more specific about the problem?  I am not sure if this explains the problem behavior you see, but it is simple enough to implement and is probably worth trying first.

Answer (score 0):

The conflict is that when i write in text area the submit button is enable even that i have no selected anything in input = file , and if delete my textarea function my input file function works normally